# React.js - Implement Socket.io / Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, hapi.js

I am trying to establish a socket connection with my React and  Hapi.js server.

This is what I have so far:

Index.js(Hapi invocation):

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
io = require("socket.io")(server.listener);
server.connection({port: config.server.port});
...
```

React component:

```
componentDidMount: function () {     
socket.on('passat', function (data) {console(data.somedata)});
},
```

In one of my controllers. I would like to emit the 'passat' event number of times, so that react component can display it.

I am banging my head how to implement something like this in my controller:

```
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('passat',{
     somedata: "data"
    });
});
```

I have tried this(one of the controllers):

```
 ...
 this.distance = options.distance;
 this.linkage = options.linkage;
 this.version = options.version;
 dispatchSocketMessage("message");
 //more code below
 }

function dispatchSocketMessage(msg) {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
       socket.emit('passat',{somedata: msg});
   });
}
```

The event is never fired.
If I try this:

```
this.distance = options.distance;
this.linkage = options.linkage;
this.version = options.version;
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.emit('passat',{somedata: msg});
});
```

Then it works, but only when I reload the page.

I would need to have a function (or similiar) where I can fire an event any number of times so that the react component will catch it.

I got it to work:
Index.js

```
io = require("socket.io")(server.listener);
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  global = function (val) {
   console.log(val)
   socket.emit('passat', val)};
 });
```

And in my controller I use it as:

```
global({
            type: 'success',
            message: "Task 1 of 2: DATA PREPARATION...",
            totalObjects: length,
            iterations: i,
            testMessage: "Message is a test one"
        });
```

This works, but I am using global var. I would like to avoid it.
How can I attach that to request.server.XXXXX
So that I can call it in my controller using request object?

Comment: Why don't you use a hapi plugin for socket.io like this one https://github.com/sibartlett/hapi-io or alternatively try https://github.com/hapijs/nes?

Comment: I have it already running. But the project is built for Web and also for Nodewebkit version. NW version we use is not compatible with ECMA6, and more importantly is using older node than the NES requires. I have transpiled the NES for NW usage, but there are problems which I do not have to hunt down.